# awk or sed to format variable durations

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, text-formatting

Tried a lot of awk and sed commands, but cant get the file to format properly. The primary issue is with handling of extra comma in the middle of a column that exits sometimes and doesnt exist other times.

This is how it looks in the csv file:

```
Num,Type,StartTime,Duration,Var1,Var2,Var3
1,Forward,9/11/2019 11:15,"15 h, 45 m",98.03,-1.38,-0.2
2,Forward,9/12/2019 13:00,"8 h, 21 m",97.84,-0.83,1.27
3,Forward,9/12/2019 21:30,"20 h, 30 m",99.06,-2.12,-1.64
4,Forward,9/14/2019 8:00,18 h,97.47,-0.84,0.07
5,Backward,9/30/2019 14:00,56 m,95.93,-0.17,1.26
```

This is how it needs to be:

```
Num,Type,StartTime,Duration,Var1,Var2,Var3
1,Forward,9/11/2019 11:15,15:45,98.03,-1.38,-0.2
2,Forward,9/12/2019 13:00,8:21,97.84,-0.83,1.27
3,Forward,9/12/2019 21:30,20:30,99.06,-2.12,-1.64
4,Forward,9/14/2019 8:00,18:00,97.47,-0.84,0.07
5,Backward,9/30/2019 14:00,0:56,95.93,-0.17,1.26
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. We need to be able to actually use the data to test our answers. We also need to know what the column separator of your file is. Is it separated by commas? Spaces? Tabs? Something else?

Comment: Adding and clarifying @terdon 's comment, just show the actual raw csv file. Are the values encompassed by quotes?

Comment: @t Updated now. Please advise.

Comment: @aviro yes, there are quotes as you can see in rows 1-3, but not in rows 4-5.

Comment: See [Can awk deal with CSV file that contains comma inside a quoted field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956933/8529284)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to ensure you're **only** modified the required field using an awk script

```
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS = "," }

function convert_time(timestr)
{
  gsub(/[" ]/, "", timestr);
  if (timestr !~ ",") {
    number = substr(timestr, 1, length(timestr) -1)
    if (timestr ~ "m$") return "0:" number
    if (timestr ~ "h$") return number ":00"
  } else {
    gsub(/[^0-9,]/,"", timestr)
    gsub(/,/,":", timestr)
    return timestr
  }
}

NR > 1 { $4 = convert_time($4) }

{ print $0 }
```

- By using the [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) variable in awk you could split CSV files even if some fields contain commas - as long as they are embedded in double quotes.
- I'm using [OFS](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html#index-OFS-variable-1) variable to ensure that when I print the modified line, the fields will be separated by commas.
- On each line (except for the first one, which I assume is the header), I convert the 4th field as requested using the `convert_time` function I wrote.
- Finally I print the modified line.

The `convert_time` function:
First, I assume that there could be only minutes and hours; If the field might also contain a day, for instance, the function won't work correctly and would need to be modified accordingly.

- I'm using `gsub` to remove any spaces or quotes from the `timestr` variable.
- If `timestr` doesn't contain any commas, it means there's a single item - either the minute or the hour.

  - I get only the number by removing the last character using `substr` function.
  - if the last character of the `timestr` variable is the m (for minutes), return 00:number
  - if the last character of the `timestr` variable is the h (for hours), return number:00
- If `timestr` contains a comma, I'm assuming the the first number is the hour, and the second one is the minute.

  - I'm using `gsub` to remove any characters that are not a digit or a comma - this will remove the h and m characters, and will keep only the digits and the comma.
  - Then I replace the comma with colon (the punctuation mark, not the internal body organ...), again using `gsub`.

I put the entire script into a file called `convert_time.awk`, and ran it.

Output:

```
$ cat file.csv | awk -f convert_time.awk
Num,Type,StartTime,Duration,Var1,Var2,Var3
1,Forward,9/11/2019 11:15,15:45,98.03,-1.38,-0.2
2,Forward,9/12/2019 13:00,8:21,97.84,-0.83,1.27
3,Forward,9/12/2019 21:30,20:30,99.06,-2.12,-1.64
4,Forward,9/14/2019 8:00,18:00,97.47,-0.84,0.07
5,Backward,9/30/2019 14:00,0:56,95.93,-0.17,1.26
```

Note that in this case it only modified a specific field - the 4th one.

Answer (score -1):

```
 sed 's/"//g' kl| awk '!/m/{gsub("h,","h,00 m,",$0)}1'| sed "s/h,/:/g"| sed "s/m,/,/g"|sed  -r "s/\s+:\s+/:/g"
```

output

```
1,Forward,9/11/2019 11:15,15:45 ,98.03,-1.38,-0.2
2,Forward,9/12/2019 13:00,8:21 ,97.84,-0.83,1.27
3,Forward,9/12/2019 21:30,20:30 ,99.06,-2.12,-1.64
4,Forward,9/14/2019 8:00,18 :00 ,97.47,-0.84,0.07
5,Backward,9/30/2019 14:00,56 ,95.93,-0.17,1.26
```

Comment: You have few issues. 1. You're assuming that there couldn't be "h" or "m character anywhere else, only in this field. 2. You have redundant spaces that are not getting removed from this modified field in the output. For instance, in the 4th line you have "18 :00 ". 3. In case the field indicates only minutes, you don't add the hour before (0:56 instead of just 56 in the last line) . 4. You remove all quotes and assume that there are no other fields that contain commas and embedded in quotes.